# How can we defer conflict resolution for SQL Express DB as Client & SQL Server as Server using Mycrosoft Sync Framework 2.0

Tags: wpf, sql-server-express, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a SQL Express DB as local server & SQL Server DB as remote server. I am using SyncOrchestrator sync Agent for Conflict Resolution. whehever there is a conflict, i want to store it, so that later on i get all the conflicts and resolve one by one. But ApplyAction enumeration doesn't have any value like 'SkipChange' or 'Defer'.

Please Guide.

the code is pasted below.

private void btnSync_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
            SqlConnection clientConn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring1);

```
        SqlConnection serverConn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring2);

        // create the sync orhcestrator
        SyncOrchestrator syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();


        SqlSyncProvider localProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("Scope1", clientConn);
        SqlSyncProvider remoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("Scope2", serverConn);

        // set local provider of orchestrator to a sync provider associated with the 
        // ProductsScope in the SyncExpressDB express client database
        syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = localProvider;

        // set the remote provider of orchestrator to a server sync provider associated with
        // the ProductsScope in the SyncDB server database
        syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = remoteProvider;

        // set the direction of sync session to Upload and Download
        syncOrchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.DownloadAndUpload;

        // subscribe for errors that occur when applying changes to the client
        ((SqlSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(Program_ApplyChangeFailed);

        // execute the synchronization process
 SyncOperationStatistics syncStats = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();             

        MessageBox.Show("Synchronization of Table1 Completed");

        BindClientTables();
        BindServerTables();
        }

    private void btnServerData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        BindServerTables();
        }

    private void btnClientData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        BindClientTables();
        }

    static void Program_ApplyChangeFailed(object sender, DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs e)
        {
        "**Here I want to defer the Resolution for future.**"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should specify RetryNextSync as the action if you want to skip ...

I suggest you don't defer the resolution that long...if you defer it and users continue to update the rows, the rows you have stored when you encountered the conflict would have changed already by the time you loop thru them to resolve the conflicts...

Comment: I want the conflicts to get stored and Manager to resolve the conflicts, when he logs in.The user will not have the permission to resolve the conflicts but to raise it only....this is the business requirement.